# Swift Firebase QueryLimitedToFirst

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

Hi I am trying to limit a feed to the most recent two posts from users. I was reading the Firebase documentation and it said simply to add "queryLimited(toFirst: Int)" and so far it has not been working, my feed still retrieves all the posts from each user. At the very top is where I have implemented the "queryLimited".

**Edit**

The way my code is right now, it is only limiting the users and not the posts(json tree below) so how can I change it to limit the posts of each user?

```
func getAllPosts(refreshing: Bool, refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").queryLimited(toFirst: 2)
    MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "businessName").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        //observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            self.feeds = []
            for item in dict {
                let json = JSON(item.value)
                let uid = json["uid"].stringValue
                var name: String = json["businessName"].stringValue
                let address: String = json["businessStreet"].stringValue
                let state: String = json["businessCity"].stringValue
                let caption: String = json["caption"].stringValue
                let downloadURL: String = json["download_url"].stringValue
                let timestamp = json["timestamp"].doubleValue
                let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp/1000)
                let postID: String = json["postID"].stringValue

                let lat = json["businessLatitude"].doubleValue
                let long = json["businessLongitude"].doubleValue
                let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

                let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                let distanceInMeters: Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                let distanceInMiles: Double = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137
                let distanceLabelText = String(format: "%.2f miles away", distanceInMiles)

                self.uid = json["uid"].stringValue

                let usersReference = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: uid)
                usersReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                        let userInfo = dict.allValues[0]
                        let userJSON = JSON(userInfo)
                        name = userJSON["name"].stringValue

                    }
                    let post = Post(uid: uid, caption: caption, downloadURL: downloadURL, name: name, date: date, address: address, state: state, distance: distanceLabelText, postID: postID)


                    self.feeds.append(post)

                    // sort posts by date/distance
                    self.feeds.sort {$0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending}
                    self.feeds.sort {$0.distance.compare($1.distance) == .orderedAscending}
                    self.feedTableView.reloadData()

                })
            }
        }
        if refreshing {
            refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        }
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
    })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the order query must precede the limit query.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "businessName").queryLimited(toFirst: 2)
```

Comment: The problem I found out was I was limiting the users in the feed and not the posts for each user. I am still trying to figure out how to limit the posts and not the users.

Comment: Oh yes I see, you want 2 posts max for each user. You can't do that with Firebase. If you are querying at node "posts" you can only retrieve 0, 1 or more users with their entire data.

Comment: thats pretty lame :(

Comment: Shallow queries are not allowed with Firebase. You can either try :
- to query at each "posts/userId/" with a limit of 2.
- or maintain a separated list of the most 2 recent posts for each user.

Comment: I'll just create a layout work around, just got to activate my creativity